# Update reps table with right values in a trigger after insert on userterritory

Tags: trigger, mariadb

I two DBs `veeva` and `pdone` as shown below in the pics

[image: veeva DB]
[image: pdone DB]

As you can see `veeva` is simple and hasn't no constraints which relies on duplicate and wrong values. The problem happen exactly on `userterritory` where a `user` is assigned to one or more `territory`. In the new DB `pdone` that is not allowed so I need to find - from `veeva` - those reps that has only one `territory` and I got that through this query:

```
    SELECT
        count(*) AS reps,
        userid,
        lastmodifieddate,
        territoryid
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                userid,
                territoryid,
                count(*) AS territories
            FROM
                userterritory
            GROUP BY
                userid
            HAVING
                territories = 1
        ) T1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id AS userid,
            lastmodifieddate
        FROM
            `user`
        WHERE
            `user`.`id` IN (
                SELECT
                    userterritory.`userid`
                FROM
                    userterritory
            )
    ) T2 USING (userid)
    GROUP BY
        territoryid
    HAVING
        reps = 1
```

After each `INSERT` on `userterritory` I execute a trigger that update `reps` table by setting up the right `territories_id` based on relationship from `userterritory`. This is the code for the trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`userterritory_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `userterritory` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    # [ VARIABLES DECLARATION ]
    DECLARE vUserID VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerritoriRep VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerrytoriLastMod DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    # [ VARIABLES ASIGNATION ]
    SET vUserID         =NEW.userid;
    SET vTerritoriRep   =(select IFNULL(reps.territories_id,'N/A') from pdone.reps where reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);
    SET vTerrytoriLastMod=(SELECT reps.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);

IF (NEW.territoryid != vTerritoriRep) THEN
    UPDATE pdone.reps 
    SET reps.territories_id = NEW.territoryid, 
        reps.lastSyncAt = IF(NOW()>vTerrytoriLastMod,NOW(),reps.lastSyncAt), 
        reps.updatedAt=now() 
    WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID; 
END IF;
END
```

All is working perfectly, but I am getting `reps` with `territories_id` nulled and that is not allowed since each `reps` has to be assigned to one `territories`. See this pic:

[image]

So, how do I apply my query to the trigger in order to get right results? Can any give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your `TRIGGER` to do this:

1. I added the `vTerritoryCount` variable.
2. If you have more than 1 rows with the same `userid` it wont update the `reps.territories_id`.

Here's the `TRIGGER`:

```
USE `veeva_new`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`userterritory_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `userterritory` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    # [ VARIABLES DECLARATION ]
    DECLARE vUserID VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerritoryRep VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerritoryLastMod DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    DECLARE vTerritoryCount INT(7) DEFAULT 0; #[060715.01]
    # [ VARIABLES ASIGNATION ]
    SET vUserID         =NEW.userid;
    SET vTerritoryRep   =(SELECT IFNULL(reps.territories_id,'N/A') FROM pdone.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);
    SET vTerritoryLastMod=(SELECT reps.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);
    SET vTerritoryCount =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM veeva_new.userterritory WHERE userterritory.userid=vUserID);
IF (NEW.territoryid != vTerritoryRep) THEN # [ IF THE NEW TERRITORYID IS DIFFERENT FROM TERRIROTYID IN reps TABLE ]
    IF (vTerritoryCount>1) THEN
        SET @Blah='There\'s more than 1 rows, I\'m not going to do anything.';
    ELSE
        UPDATE pdone.reps 
        SET reps.territories_id = NEW.territoryid, 
            reps.lastSyncAt = IF(NOW()>vTerritoryLastMod,NOW(),reps.lastSyncAt), 
            reps.updatedAt=now() 
        WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID;
    END IF;
END IF;
END
```